# Putting same columns of matrix to cell in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation, cell

I have a matrix which looks like as shown in the figure. What i want to do is to put all the columns (starting from the second column) with same column name ('32,32','42,42') in a cell along with the corresponding elements in the column 1. Can anyone suggest me how to go forward?

[image: matrix file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image, it seems that the columns with the same "column name" always appear 
as a pair side by side. If this is always the case, you may use the following:

```
for i = 2:2:size(data,2)
    myCell{i/2} = [data(2:end,1) data(2:end,[i, i+1])];
end
```

Otherwise, you will have to search for columns with the same "column name":

```
columnNames = unique(data(1,2:end));
myCell = cell(1,numel(columnNames));
for i = 1:numel(myCell)
    idx = data(1,:) == columnNames(i);
    myCell{i} = [data(2:end,1), data(2:end,idx)];
end
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for .